#  [NSWorkspace notificationCenter] vs. NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the difference between using `[NSWorkspace notificationCenter]` or using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`? What are they intended to be used for and what are the pros and cons of each?

I am trying to understand this by reading the Apple documentation but it doesn't shed much light on it. It says that `[NWorkspace notificationCenter]` "Returns the notification center for workspace notifications". How would I know what is would be a workspace notification? I have an observer that observes changes in the active app and uses a workspace notification:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowChangeNotification:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];`
```

But I've read sample code that mentioned that if you want to detect the screen turning off you would use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenIsLocked:) name:@"com.apple.screenIsLocked" object:nil];
```

I would have thought you would use similar ways to detect these notifications. But you use different notification centers. Can someone help me out?

Comment: It's not really clear what's not clear to you. There's one set of notifications posted by the workspace, and another that are handled by the distributed notifications center (these come from other applications). The workspace notifications are [listed in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIEFIDI). Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just did the job for the OP. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Yea I didn't understand that NSDistributedNotificationCenter only deals with notifications from other applications. It is confusing because I didn't think of screen lock (as in my example above) coming from an application.